# Python Q-Q and P-P plot of two distributions of unequal length

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, statistics, statsmodels

I am not sure what the best/most statistically sound way to accomplish what I want is, but I am basically trying to take a distribution of p-values and compare it to a much larger distribution of p-values created by permuting my original data. I am working with small p-values, so I am actually comparing the log10 of the p-values.

I have been trying to figure out a good general way to compare two arrays with similar values but unequal lengths. What I really want is something like `scipy.qqplot(dataset1, dataset2)`, but that doesn't exist, the Q-Q plot only compares your distribution to an established distribution (this question has been asked for R also: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12392/how-to-compare-two-datasets-with-q-q-plot-using-ggplot2).

Essentially this amounts to comparing two histograms. I can use np.linspace to force the exact same bins for each distribution:

```py
bins = 100
mx = max(np.max(vector1), np.max(vector2))
mn = min(np.min(vector2), np.max(vector2))
boundaries = np.linspace(mn, mx, bins, endpoint=True)
labels = [(boundaries[i]+boundaries[i+1])/2 for i in range(len(boundaries)-1)]
```

I can then easily use these boundaries and labels to make two histograms, weighted by the length of the original vectors. The easiest thing to do is just just use a few bins and plot them as histograms on the same axis, like in this question:

However, I really want something more like a Q-Q plot, and I want to use a lot of bins, so that I can see even small deviations from the 1-to-1 line. The problem with just plotting the two histograms, is that they look like this:

[image: histogram_example]

The two plots are just right on top of each other, I can't see anything.

So what I want to figure out, is how to compare these two histograms *while maintaining the bin labels*. I can easily plot the two against each other as a scatter graph, but that ends up being indexed by the bin frequency:

[image: definitely wrong]

What I really want, is to just compare the two histograms, or to make a Q-Q plot of the differences, but I cannot come up with a good statistically sound way of doing this. I can find no methods that allow me to make a Q-Q plot with two datasets instead of one dataset and a built in distribution, and I can't find any way of plotting two distributions of unequal length against each other.

For reference, here are the two histograms that went into creating that plot, you can see that they are extremely similar:

[image: histograms]

I know there must be a good way of doing this, because it seems so obvious, but I am new to this kind of thing, and relatively new to scipy, pandas, and statsmodels also.

I intentionally have not provided an example distribution here, because I wasn't sure how to make a minimal set of arrays that were non-normally distributed and captured what I am trying to do; plus the point is to be able to do this for any two overlapping unequal-length arrays.

What I want to know is what is the right/best way to approach this problem in python in a statistically sound way? Is there some way of creating a distribution from the permuted data that could be used for a statsmodels or scipy Q-Q plot? Is there a way to compare two histograms visually like this already? Is there a way of making probability plots that I don't know about?

---

**Edit: Trying cumulative and manual Q-Q plots**

Thanks to @user333700's answer, I figured out how to create a manual QQ plot for the data, and also a cumulative probability plot. I created the plots using data with an overlapping min/max but the following distributions:

[image: manufactured distributions]

QQ plot:

```py
q = np.linspace(0, 100, 101)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(np.percentile(ytest, q), np.percentile(xtest, q))
```

[image: qqplot]

So that works really well with simple data, the cumulative plot is similar:

```py
# Pick bins
x = ytest
y = xtest
boundaries = sorted(x)[::round(len(x)/bins)+1]
labels = [(boundaries[i]+boundaries[i+1])/2 for i in range(len(boundaries)-1)]

# Bin two series into equal bins
xb = pd.cut(x, bins=boundaries, labels=labels)
yb = pd.cut(y, bins=boundaries, labels=labels)

# Get value counts for each bin and sort by bin
xhist = xb.value_counts().sort_index(ascending=True)/len(xb)
yhist = yb.value_counts().sort_index(ascending=True)/len(yb)

# Make cumulative
for ser in [xhist, yhist]:
    ttl = 0
    for idx, val in ser.iteritems():
        ttl += val
        ser.loc[idx] = ttl

# Plot it
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,6))
ax.scatter(xhist, yhist)
plt.show()
```

[image: cumulative plot]

Going back to my actual skewed data (where the two distributions are extremely similar in every way except the lengths) and adding a 1-to-1 line, I get this for those two:

[image: plots with real data]

So both work, which is great, and the cumulative probability plot shows quite clearly that there is no large difference in the data, but the Q-Q plot shows that there is a small difference in the tail.

Comment: small change for pp-plot: The histogram has equal length bins (length in terms of the original values), so pp-plot is still unequal spaced. What we use for pp-plot is equal weight bins. For example use bin boundaries defined by every k-th observation of x, bin both series with these bins and then plot. In this case the x cumulative histogram frequency will be equal spaced in [0,1].

Comment: @user333700: could you clarify please? I am afraid I don't follow what you mean by equal weight bins in this context. Could you provide a pseudocode example of how I would do that?

Comment: In your probability plot the x-coordinate of your points corresponds to the cumulative probability for each bin. Because the bins have different frequencies or counts, the x-coordinate of the points are moved towards the end where most of the probability is, e.g. you have only two bins below the median. If instead you choose bin bounds so that the bins have equal frequencies for the x variable, then the plot points would be equal spaced on the x-axis. Something like `boundaries = sorted(x)[::k]` and adjustments for endpoints. With "equal weights" I meant equal frequency in each bin for x.

Comment: @user333700: Thanks, that was very helpful. Would you mind taking a quick look to see if my edit addresses your point without breaking anything?

Comment: The probability plot is now equal spaced on x, i.e. boundaries looks correct. However, I'm not familiar enough with pandas to understand the code just by reading. Given the differences in the two distributions in your example, the probability plot points should be bowed or bent away from the 45 degree line. If it's your actual data with essentially equal distributions, then it confirms that the distributions do not differ in any parts of the distribution.

Comment: (Aside: qq-plot makes outliers and differences in tails more visible, pp-plot makes differences in the center more visible, because end points are fixed at 0 and 1.)

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, that is why the outlier is more obvious in Q-Q plot version. And yes, the final image is plotted from the actual data, the individual histograms I am comparing can be seen here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dlx0.png (figure 3 above). They are *extremely* similar, the only difference other than the length should be at the very tail end of the distribution. The two plots you taught me how to do show that. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of statistical tests, scipy has a two sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test for the continuous variables. The binned histogram data can be used with a chisquare test. scipy.stats also has a k-sample Anderson-Darling test.

For plotting:

The equivalent of a probability plot for two histograms would be to plot the cumulative frequencies for the two samples, i.e. with cumulative probabilities on each axis corresponding to the bin boundaries.

statsmodels has a qq-plot for two sample comparison, however it currently assumes that the sample sizes are the same. If the sample sizes are different, then the quantiles need to be computed for the same probabilities.
https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/2896
https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/pull/3169
(I don't remember what the status of this is.)

Comment: Thanks @user333700. The tests you recommend are great. I am not sure exactly how to do a bivariate cumulative plot though; I tried just doing a really simple version and I ended up with the majority of my points clustered in the upper right of the chart. Is there some special magic I need to do to make this sensible?

Comment: Also, I am actually struggling to understand why we would use quantiles instead of set boundaries... if the two distributions are different, then surly the quantile would be less useful? If the quantile comparison is the way to go, is there a reason I can't just use pandas.qcut to create two equal length quantile arrays and then plot them against each other as a scatter plot? Or is that not what a Q-Q plot actually is?

Comment: I never used qcut but it looks like it's returning the category instead of the value. Plotting np.percentiles(x, q), np.percentiles(y, q), for q = np.linspace(0, 100, 101) on each axis might work for qq plot. An actual QQPlot would do the same but for the data points instead of fixed grid.

Comment: If your data is very skewed, as it looks like, a qq-plot will always be bunched together. In this case a pp-plot might be better, which has the cdf probability on the axis. This could be plotted directly from the cumulative histogram frequency, i.e. something like plot(cumhist_x, cumhist_y) assuming both histograms have the same bounds/bins.